# Trying to get a column value of an ancestor when using HIERARCHYID

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

I'm evaluating the HIERARCHYID data type to see if it'll meet my needs for a project. I was hoping to use it to get the manager of a given employee ID. I'm looking at tables in the AdventureWorks DB (the 2012 version), specifically the Person.Person and HumanResources.Employee tables.

My query goes something like this:

```
SELECT 
    pp.LastName + ', ' + pp.FirstName AS Name,
    CAST(hre.NationalIdNumber AS BIGINT) AS Id,
    hre.LoginID,
    hre.OrganizationNode.GetAncestor(1) AS ManagerId,
    hre.JobTitle,
    hre.BirthDate,
    hre.MaritalStatus,
    hre.Gender,
    hre.HireDate
FROM 
    Person.Person pp
INNER JOIN 
    HumanResources.Employee hre ON pp.BusinessEntityID = hre.BusinessEntityID
```

Now I expected that because GetAncestor() is a CLR function that I'd have been able to do something like hre.OrganizationNode.GetAncestor(1).NationalIdNumber AS ManagerId but I get told that I'm not worthy very fast.

What is it that I'm doing wrong here?

**EDIT Later on**

Playing around leads me to this but this is hardly optimal (or is it?)

```
SELECT
    pp.LastName + ', ' + pp.FirstName AS Name,
    CAST(hre.NationalIdNumber AS BIGINT) AS Id,
    hre.LoginID,
    NULL AS ManagerId,
    hre.JobTitle,
    hre.BirthDate,
    hre.MaritalStatus,
    hre.Gender,
    hre.HireDate,
    hre.OrganizationLevel
FROM 
    Person.Person pp
INNER JOIN 
    HumanResources.Employee hre ON pp.BusinessEntityID = hre.BusinessEntityID
WHERE 
    OrganizationLevel = 0
UNION
SELECT
    pp.LastName + ', ' + pp.FirstName AS Name,
    CAST(hre.NationalIdNumber AS BIGINT) AS Id,
    hre.LoginID,
    CAST(hre2.NationalIDNumber AS BIGINT) AS ManagerId,
    hre.JobTitle,
    hre.BirthDate,
    hre.MaritalStatus,
    hre.Gender,
    hre.HireDate,
    hre.OrganizationLevel
FROM 
    Person.Person pp
INNER JOIN 
    HumanResources.Employee hre ON pp.BusinessEntityID = hre.BusinessEntityID
INNER JOIN 
    HumanResources.Employee hre2 ON hre.OrganizationNode.GetAncestor(1) = hre2.OrganizationNode
ORDER BY
    hre.OrganizationLevel ASC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A correlated sub-query seems to do it for me:

```
SELECT 
    pp.LastName + ', ' + pp.FirstName AS Name,
    CAST(hre.NationalIdNumber AS BIGINT) AS Id,
    hre.LoginID,
    (
        SELECT NationalIDNumber
        FROM HumanResources.Employee AS m
        WHERE OrganizationNode = hre.OrganizationNode.GetAncestor(1)
    )AS ManagerId,
    hre.JobTitle,
    hre.BirthDate,
    hre.MaritalStatus,
    hre.Gender,
    hre.HireDate
FROM 
    Person.Person pp
INNER JOIN 
    HumanResources.Employee hre ON pp.BusinessEntityID = hre.BusinessEntityID
```

Comment: Thanks Ben, that does the job in less verbose fashion than mine